# need to create a link with button

Tags: javascript, html

i have this html code

```
<a class="vote" action="id" id="1"> text </a>
```

and this is js function of this button.

```
 $('.vote').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var competitionvotes = $(this).attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: id,
                competitionvotes: competitionvotes
            },
            url: 'http://'+window.location.hostname+'/ajax/vote_ajax',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == 'success') {
                    $("."+id).css("display", "none");
                    $("."+id+'_v').css("display", "block");
                }
                if (data == 'fail') {
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

how to corectly creeate link? example `domain.com/?action=id&id=1` (is not work this example)

Comment: Does it not work in some special way? Handler doesn't get called? You get a TypeError? You get a network error? The browser sets on fire?

Comment: Attribute "action" on <a> is not valid HTML.

Comment: action is a number

example is id=20&competitionvotes=1

Comment: @user3555881 No! your question says something else.....^^

Answer (score 0):

As you want to create this query string:

```
?action=id&id=1
```

but in your ajax data you are using `post` and sending other key here:

```
data: {
    id: id,
    action: competitionvotes //<----change the key to action
},
```

and you can change the `type:"GET"`, if you want to send the data in the url.